# Why am I getting an error in [dictionary length]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Here i want to display image url to the image view,

```
NSData *imageData= [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sharedDelegate.getHotListArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]objectForKey:@"image"];
cell.userGetHotImgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Here i got error like dictionary length ?
Please help me how can i pass the array of image  url to nsdata ?

Thank you in-advance.

Comment: Please post the whole error message, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: Helpful hint: your first statement is doing 4 things in one statement: creating NSData, creating a NSURL, fetching that URL's contents, and getting data out of a dictionary.  When you get an error (as in this case), you need to break it apart into the 4 things it's doing, so you can isolate the error.  Why not just write your code this way in the first place. Super-tightly packed code doesn't run any faster, and ofter doesn't run at all!

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have posted you are creating an NSData object and then calling `objectForKey:` on it. This is not a method of NSData.

Just assign the NSData you created to your imageData variable.